# Ansible loop with dict as ansible_loop_var key/value; error `argument 'release_values' is of type <class 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict`

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use the `kubernetes.core.helm` module in a loop with the following code:

```yaml
    - name: Install Helm charts
      kubernetes.core.helm:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        chart_ref: "{{ item.ref }}"
        namespace: apps
        create_namespace: yes
        wait: yes
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig.path }}"
        values: "{{ item.values | default(omit) }}"
      loop:
        - name: appA
          ref: repo/appA
          values:
            installCRDs: true
        - name: appB
          ref: "https://<fqdn>/chart_appB.tgz"
        - name: appC
          ref: "https://<fqdn>/chart_appC.tgz"
```

I'm getting the error (on all 3 iterations):
`argument 'release_values' is of type <class 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value`.

How can I make this loop work with the `values` key passed as an actual dictionary?

I have tried all kinds of different jinja filters, or different syntax's, changed the name of the key `values` to another, but basically keep getting the same error.

EDIT:
I also tried removing `default(omit)` entirely in combination with the list below, but it made no difference.

```yaml
      [...]
      loop:
        - name: appA
          ref: repo/appA
          values:
            installCRDs: true
        - name: appB
          ref: "https://<fqdn>/chart_appB.tgz"
          values: ~
        - name: appC
          ref: "https://<fqdn>/chart_appC.tgz"
          values: ~
```

Comment: Do not quote [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional). Correct syntax is ``default(omit)``. To explain the error: The parameter *values* requires a dictionary. Instead of omitting the parameter, you submitted the string 'omit'. It's a trivial bug/typo. You might want to close the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax. Unfortunately, with `default(omit)` I'm still getting the same error (I am and was getting the error for all 3 iterations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a combination of wrong syntax of `default(omit)` and using a reserved keyword (`.values` being a shorthand for `.values()`).

Issue resolved :)